# adding image in url action link inside input button?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to add image button inside an input button which has url.action method

```
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="View Chart" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Multigraph", "Home")'"/>
```

Actually i want to do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCvdY.jpg)

On click of the image i will be able to go to the specific view

I have also looked into [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627178/how-to-insert-image-in-html-action-link-asp-net-mvc)

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Use styles and background-image :)

Comment: You have to take extra div or span tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could style the input button with css.

```css
.btn--graph {
    width: 110px;
    height: 93px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCvdY.jpg');
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn--graph" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Multigraph", "Home")'"/>
```

However if this button is actually a link to another webpage. It would semantically be more correct to use an anchor link.

```html
<a href="@Url.Action("Multigraph", "Home")">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCvdY.jpg" alt="View Chart">
</a>
```

Comment: You are a life saver :)