# image does not show up when when calling from @Html.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an odd issue. I simplified what I my issue is.

Within my _Layout.cshtml, I have the following code. The image shows up fine.

```
<img src="~/Content/images/draw.png" />
```

Instead, if I replace it with the following:

```
 @Html.Action("RetrieveLogo", "Info")
```

And do the following:

```
    public string RetreiveLogo()
    {
        return $"<img src=\"~/Content/images/draw.png\"/>";
    }
```

The image does not show up. I see it hitting RetreiveLogo and returning the value. It does not show the image though.

As mentioned, what I have above is simplified as my content is more dynamic than this. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: a see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627178/how-to-insert-image-in-html-action-link-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public ActionResult RetreiveLogo()
{
    return PartialView("<img src=\"~/Content/images/draw.png\"/>");
}
```